# Alien Quote, "We are human"

Tags: story-identification

I remember seeing a tv show in the 1970s where a human and an alien were on the moon. The human put his space helmet in direct contact with the alien's helmet to communicate, and the alien said, "We are human!"
It was not the U.F.O. episode, "Survival", as I thought.
Does anybody remember this, and can help me?
Thank you.

Comment: This vaguely reminds me of Enemy Mine (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enemy_Mine_%28film%29) but I don't remember the scene you mention, and that's '85, so it's probably not that.